# Problem with image links: difference in behavior (IE vs Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

An image as a link:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
  <img border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="logo_w3s.gif" width="100" 
       height="100">
</a>
```

The above code behaves differently in IE and Chrome.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image

In IE, when I tried to dragout the image it used to create a shortcut to 
the href specified in the anchor tag. and also it used the alt attribute 
to set the name of the short cut.

But it Chrome, It uses the image src attribute to download the image.

Is there any workaround to make it similar to IE in chrome as well?

An image as a link:

```
<a draggable="true" href="https://www.w3schools.com"> <img draggable="false" border="0" width="100" height="100" style='background: url(/tags/logo_w3s.gif);'></img>
</a>
```

I tried the above solution in Chrome, It helps in creating the shortcut 
pointing to the `href` specified in the anchor tag. but it doesn't uses 
the alt of the image.

If i tried to make

```
<a...>W3Schools<img...></a>
```

It helped but the string W3Schools is displayed as part of the page.

Comment: <p>
An image as a link: <a draggable="true"  href="https://www.w3schools.com">
<img draggable="false"  border="0" width="100" height="100" style='background: url(/tags/logo_w3s.gif);'></img>
</a>

</p>